# Foreach loop doesn't working in .cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

My problem: I want to list categories through _Layout.cshtml, and I use Partial View to do that.

I have this in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GenreMenu", "Shop");}
```

In GenreMenu.cshtml, when I write this, everything works fine:

```
@model IEnumerable<webshop.Models.Genre>
<div class="list-group" style="float: left">   

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">FPS</a>      
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Manager</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Strategy</a>   
</div>
```

But when I use this way, nothing happens(no exception, nothing, it just wont create the list:

```
<div class="list-group" style="float: left">  
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">@item.Name</a>
    }
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What model are you declaring for the partial view?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<webshop.Models.Genre>

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your model to the partial or an action that returns the partial.

You could use the following providing it matches the model in your partial.

```
@Html.Partial("GenreMenu", "Shop", Model)
```

Or pass it to an action that returns the partial

```
@Html.Action("GenreMenu", "Shop", Model)
```